# Next js pass props down when using children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component like this inside a Next js page:

```
 ...
     <Chart
        isShoppingChartOpen={isShoppingChartOpen}
        toggleShoppingChart={toggleChartVisibility}
        lineItems={lineItems}
      />

      <main className="relative">
        <div>{children}</div>
      </main>
...
```

I would need to pass `toggleChartVisibility` to children too. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it as a prop to every child You can try something like this:

```
 children = children.map((el) => {
    let props = el.props;
    props.toggleChartVisibility = "Value";
    return <ChildrenComponent props={props} children={el.children}/>
  });
```

you can sadly not alter props of the children elements directly after they are created. So it would probably be the best to insert the props you want into the children, right when they are created.